# easelJS - Resize an image with Javascript then use it with SpriteSheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, easeljs, sprite-sheet

In my code, I have an image stored into a variable directly load from Javascript (I didn't create any HTML tag link to this image)and this image is in High Definition.

Depending on the screen size of the user, I would like to resize the image with specific values (width and height) and I already calculated these values.
I modified the size of the image using Javascript

```
imgHD.width = modifiedWidth;
imgHD.height= modifiedHeight;
```

This is working nice.
I checked it using

```
alert('newWidth: ' + imgHD.width + ' / newHeight: ' + imgHD.height);
```

and the values are corrects.

I create the SpriteSheet and easelJS used the image in HD without the width and height modifications.

```
var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    // image to use
    images: [imgHD],
    // width, height & registration point of each sprite
    frames: { width: imgHD.width / imgSpriteNbr, height: imgHD.height / imgSpriteNbr, regX: imgHD.width / imgSpriteNbr / 2, regY: imgHD.height / imgSpriteNbr / 2},
    animations: {
        walk: [0, imgSpriteNbr - 1, "walk"]
    }
});
```

Could I resize my image directly from easelJS, could I resize the image from Javascript in another way which could be interpreted correctly by easelJS after ?

I'm a beginner with easelJS,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create the SpriteSheet at a different size, you would have to use an intermediary canvas, and draw your image at a different size first, and then use it with a SpriteSheet.

An easier way would be to just scale the sprites created from the SpriteSheet.